# Monotouch custom UITableViewCell GetCell not initialising new custom view cells

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've been foloowing a number of tutorials to put together a custom table view cell using storyboard for a prototype table view.

I'm new to monotouch and managed to get a working solution for standard cell types.  Running into issues with custom view cells as I'm unable to initialise a fresh cell in the correct manner.  Some old tutorials appear to load a cell nib file but I'm using storyboard with the below code.

Where am I going wrong?

(I would use monotouch dialog but not couldn't figure out a way to add lovely uipickerviews on accessory, etc in a simple manner).

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_5_-_using_xcode%2C_interface_builder%2C_and_storyboards

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    // in a Storyboard, Dequeue will ALWAYS return a cell
    //*** above comment doesnt seem to hold for custom uitableview cells
    UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
    // now set the properties as normal
    cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItems[indexPath.Row].Name;
    if (tableItems[indexPath.Row].Done) 
        cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
    else
        cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
    return cell;
}


// here's my implementation of GetCell but problem is that I can't seem to generate a new cell
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
        _cellIdentifier = "SingleTimeViewCell";
        CustomViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (_cellIdentifier) as 

//      if (cell == null)
//      {
//          cell = new SingleTimeViewCell();
//      }

         cell.myCustomProperty = "hello";
         return cell;
}

// here's the auto generated CustomViewCell class from Xcode storyboard
public partial class CustomViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public CustomViewCell () : base()  // I added this ctor but it didnt seem to help matters
    {
    }

    public CustomViewCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    { 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using only storyboards with prototype cells, see [this sample from Xamarin forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/23067/#Comment_23067).

Here is the relevant code (credit to Stephane Cordonnier):

```cs
public partial class CustomCellStoryBoardViewController : UIViewController
{
    public CustomCellStoryBoardViewController(IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        this.MyTableView.DataSource = new MyDataSource();
    }

    private class MyDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
    {
        private String[] items = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };

        public MyDataSource()
        {
        }

        public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, int section)
        {
            return this.items.Length;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            MyCustomCell cell = (MyCustomCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(MyCustomCell.Key);
            cell.SetTitle(this.items[indexPath.Row]);
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

The custom cell:

```cs
[Register ("MyCustomCell")]
public class MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    [Outlet]
    MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel TitleLabel { get; set; }

    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("MyCustomCell");

    public MyCustomCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public void SetTitle(String title)
    {
        this.TitleLabel.Text = title;
    }
}
```

Make sure you have set the custom cell class and identifier to the name of your cell class in the storyboard.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, which inspector property do I set to "Make sure you have set the custom cell class in the storyboard"?

Comment: @HOCA In Xamarin Studio under Widget, both "Identity -> Class" and "Table View Cell -> Identifier" should be set to the name of your custom cell class.

Answer (score 0):

In your .xib file, for that cell, are you using the same cell identifier 'SingleTimeViewCell'.  I'm not sure exactly how you've created your custom cell but I know I had what sounds like the same issue.

Comment: In storyboard I'm able to directly add a view cell and edit it's contents, labels, etc.  I have seen the tutorials editing it in a seperate xib file.  But isn't storyboard and IOS 6 allow in storyboard editing as described?

Answer (score 0):

You cant'd do it with storyboard. Use main storyboard and separate xib files for the cells.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'm still learning but I managed to get the custom cell loaded at this stage with the following entry in the parent tableview controller's constructor so that it loads the xib file holding the cell view along with the cell identifier:     TableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(UINib.FromName("SingleTimeViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle), "SingleTimeViewCell");       One more small step towards my animated custom tablecell views :)

Answer (score 0):

I read so mush non sense about tableview cell and reuse and Xib, 
Almost every sample code a found jsute don't reuse properly...

on iOS6 and further the simplest way to do it :

1. create a new UITABLEVIEWCELL from Xamarin. (let's say MyCustomCell)
2. in InterfaceBuilder set the Identifier of the cell to the value of MyCustomCell.Key (found the value in MyCsutomCell.cs created by Xamarin Studio)
3. In your ViewController Register the nib this way :

`tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse (MyCsutomCell.Nib, MyCsutomCell.Key);`

4. then on the GetCell méthode in your dataSource symple dequeue a cell (it will create one if none exists):

`MyCsutomCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (MyCsutomCell.Key) as MyCsutomCell;`